# Is Socket.io secure if you use HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, socket.io, tls1.2

I'm implementing a chatplatform using Node.js, Express and Socket.io. I've now changed my server to use HTTPS instead of normal HTTP. However, I am wondering, does this also secure messages emited between my sockets by the client/server? For example, is all my data send from socket to socket now also encrypted?

**Code as I have it right now:**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();
const path    = require('path');
const server = require('https').createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.cert')
}, app)
const io      = require('socket.io')(server);
```

I've read conflicting info when I tried searching about this online, with a lot of information being >7 years old. I hope someone could bring me some more clarity this way, as I unfortunatly cannot sniff my localhost traffic (Windows user).

Comment: Is it secure?  That's a really broad ranging question that could encompass a lot of things such as authentication, safety of your server installation, protection of https keys, etc.... 
The communication channel itself is encrypted so it is secure from man-in-the-middle listeners (assuming your https server is properly deployed).  When you connect your socket.io to your https server, then all communication on the socket.io connection is encrypted by TLS encryption (using public key/private key encryption) the same way regular https communication would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as long as you are connecting over https and are using valid certs which from your code snippet seems that you are doing all messages transferred over that socket will be encrypted by standard https protocol.